# A query return only records that has the max value of field group by another field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a query that has the following result:

```
month     OP#     JOB #   SumProd   SumScrap    
1     10      9870    2105      21  
1     20      9870    2018      3   
1     30      9870    2018      0   
1     10      8115    14581     88  
1     20      8115    14569     35  
1     10      8114    14581     90  
1     20      8114    16180     268
```

what I want to get is the result that filter this result as only the Highest OP# of Every JOB#...

I tried like

```
SELECT month, Max(OP#) as maxOP, JOB # ... FROM ... GROUP BY [JOB #]...
```

But in access, it doesnt work...I appreciate if anyone could help me...I am waiting online...

Answer (score 0):

If access supports derived tables, this type of query will get you what you want.

```
select yourfields
from sometables
join (
select field1, max(field2) maxvalue
from table1
where whatever
group by field1 
) temp on table1.field1 = temp.field1 and table1.field2 = maxvalue
where whatever
```

Make sure that the two where clauses are as similar as possible.